# What is the alternative in harmonyos for ValueAnimator.ofInt(int... values)?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am creating a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK. Where I have to work on Animation for animate component.
I have to animates component between int values. For that I need the instance of **AnimatorValue(In Android ValueAnimator)**.

In Android we can create instance of ValueAnimator and pass int values like this:

```
ValueAnimator finalPositionAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(10, 100);
```

but, In HMOS I am able to create instance of AnimatorValue using below code:

```
AnimatorValue finalPositionAnimator = new AnimatorValue();
```

but, I am not able to set int values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as follow.

First create getAnimatedValue() util function as follow.

```
public static float getAnimatedValue(float fraction, int... values) {
        if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (values.length == 1) {
            return values[0] * fraction;
        } else {
            if (fraction == 1) {
                return values[values.length - 1];
            }
            float oneFraction = 1f / (values.length - 1);
            float offFraction = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
                if (offFraction + oneFraction >= fraction) {
                    return values[i] + (fraction - offFraction) * (values.length - 1) * (values[i + 1] - values[i]);
                }
                offFraction += oneFraction;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Then, you can use above method like this way

```
AnimatorValue animatorValue = new AnimatorValue();
animatorValue.setValueUpdateListener((animatorValue, v) -> {
         float value = AnimationUtils.getAnimatedValue(v, 10, 100);
});
```

You can see more methods similar like **ofInt()** under AnimatorValue [here](https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/openharmony_tpc_docs/blob/master/animation/ValueAnimator.md)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no similar method in HarmonyOS. You can try the following method to set the integer:

```
AnimatorValue animatorValue = new AnimatorValue();
animatorValue.setDuration(3000);
animatorValue.setValueUpdateListener((AnimatorValue animation, float value) -> {
    int finalValue = (int) (value * 90 + 10);
});
animatorValue.start();
```